# How to increase the value by +1 in the string(java) and the string is mentioned below

Tags: java

**"Sales Docket successfully saved and sent for approval. Please note your document number. JBHL/39/16-17"**

i want only the number **39** in the string should be increased by +1 when we run the method

Comment: Run what method? Can you be a little clearer? From what I can understand from your question you should consider RegEx

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to find the number, then build new string:

```
private static String increment(String input) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("/(\\d+)/").matcher(input);
    if (! m.find())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid document number: " + input);
    int newNumber = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) + 1;
    return input.substring(0, m.start(1)) + newNumber + input.substring(m.end(1));
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(increment("JBHL/39/16-17"));
```

*Output*

```
JBHL/40/16-17
```